# Uniformly continuous extension

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Given $h$ be continuous function over $\mathbb{Q}$, the set of rational numbers, show that it has uniformly continuous extension on $\mathbb{R}$.

I am struggling to define the function value and limit at $x$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ to make the extension work.

Comment: $h$ should be uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. The function
$$
h(x) = \cases{1 & if $x^2 > 2$\\0 & otherwise}
$$
is continuous on $\Bbb Q$, but has no continuous extension (uniform or otherwise) to $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is any continuous function on $\mathbb R$ which is not uniformly continuous (eg. $x^{2}$) then its restriction to $\mathbb Q$ provides a counterexample. However, if it is given that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb Q$ then it has a uniformly continuous extension to $\mathbb R$: let $x \in \mathbb R$ and choose a sequence of ratinal numbers $x_n \to x$. Then $|f(x_n)-f(x_m)| \to 0$ as $n, m \to \infty$ so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$ exists. Can you verify that this defines the required extension? Will be glad to provide more details if needed.